# Node js отслеживание новых записей в БД mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Всем привет!
При добавлении новой записи в бд mysql (хоть откуда, даже из phpmyadmin) мне нужно написать в console.log('Новая запись с ID (id записи)'); как это можно сделать в node.js ?

Comment: Возможный вариант: триггер на стороне MySQL, который при добавлении новой записи фиксирует этот факт в служебной таблице, плюс периодический опрос содержимого этой таблицы со стороны клиента, и выводе сообщения, если таблица непуста (с очисткой содержимого таблицы или только записи, ID из которой был выведен).

Comment: Какой самый простой вариант?

Comment: MySQL по-любому никого оповещать об изменениях не станет (если не нарисовать свою собственную UDF/SP под это дело с асинхронным push). Так что только поллинг.

Comment: А можно в коде пожалуйста? Я не очень шарю (новичок)